# Can I get the size of an array returned from a function in C?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

My function *arrayReturn()* returns the address of array *a*.
In *main()* I assign the address to a pointer *p* and I print the array.
Is there any way to know the size of the array from the function? Assuming we don't know the size,
it is  possible, instead of `for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)` to write something like
`for(i = 0; i < sizeof(p); i++)`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int * arrayReturn();

int main() 
{
    int *p = arrayReturn();
    
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(p+i));
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int * arrayReturn()
{
    static int a[] = {11, 22, 33};
    return &a;
}
```

Comment: Short answer: no.  This is a fundamental aspect of the way pointers work in C: By itself, a pointer just points somewhere; there's no automatic mechanism that tracks *how many* things it might point to.  It's up to you to track that yourself somehow.  (There are many ways of doing so.)

Comment: Well, yes - add a `size_t* n` parameter to the function and write the array's size to that.

Answer (score 4):

Pointers store the address of a *single* object - that object may be the first element of an array, it may be an element in the middle of an array, or it may be a single object that isn't part of an array.

There's no way to determine from the pointer value itself whether it points to an element of an array or not.

You'll have to return the array size as a separate item, either as a writable parameter or as a member of a `struct` type that also stores the pointer.